# How to automate Azure AD authentication that requires MFA authenticator code?

Tags: azure-active-directory, automated-tests, emulation, multi-factor-authentication, authenticator

We are working on E2E tests for a web app that uses Azure AD and requires MFA code from a mobile Authenticator app during login. Is there any programmatic implementation of such Authenticator that we can use during user registration and subsequently in our automated tests? Changing login procedure is not an option.

Comment: Can you please clarify your ask what you are trying to achieve? if i assume correctly you want to automate the MFA programmatically like getting the code and providing it.

Comment: Yes. Possibly with an Authenticator emulator of some sort?

Comment: Hello @Ivan , If the answer was helpful, Could you please Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score -1):

Authenticator app is always used to get the authorization of a user which is already registered or added in the Azure AD by the administrator for a particular access of an application.

It cannot be implemented programmatically to automate for authenticator code. Because the purpose of MFA will be lost. MFA came into picture to avoid the malware attack or unauthorize access of an application. so, this is not possible right now and even it won't be possible in future as well.